# Convert YouTube/Vimeo video into silent, animated images (think "moving pictures" from Harry Potter)?

Tags: javascript, ios, video, html5-video

How could you programmatically convert a YouTube/Vimeo video into a series of animated images that each reflect 5 seconds of the video? Essentially, the goal is to deconstruct the video into silent, 5-second animated pictures -- think "moving pictures" from Harry Potter.

One option is to slice the video into 5-second video chunks, but the output should feel like animated GIFs ... that is, play instantly, be lighter than combining 150 pictures into one JavaScript slideshow (assuming 30 FPS), but have the image quality of a JPG or PNG. If this is possible with video, then it's an option we're open to exploring.

Another option is to take screen shots of the video, but that is not programmatic.

Ideas?

The output needs to get rendered in HTML5 on Mobile Safari.

Comment: Why don't you use a normal video? Even a gif needs its time to load.

Answer (score 4):

You've a bit of a problem here — quality is directly related to file size. So if you create a video of 30fps (higher than regular broadcast TV, really?), you're going to run into issues with it being light & fast loading.

I don't know if I'd go down the route of making actual GIFs if you're looking for a high-ish framerate, but if it's for a web project, HTML5 video tag should be able to have autoplaying video that integrates into the page fairly seemlessly.

What you would want to do here is take a programme like [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/), put the video at the highest possible compression settings (lowest quality/framerate) & slowly bring it up until you have something that you think is the minimum you can get away with.

From there, you can look into scripting the process using these settings & something like [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). You'll probably also want to remove video metadata to save as much filespace as possible.